# Android , socket.io , Error while handshaking , when connecting to a nodejs server

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

All I want is connect from my android app to my nodejs server , I'm using genymotion by the way.

what is wrong here :

node server :

```
    var server = require('http').Server();
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('echo', function(data) {
        socket.emit('echo back', data);
      });
    });
    server.listen(12123,"127.0.0.1");
```

Android :

```
    SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://127.0.0.1:12123");
       socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
           @Override
           public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
               if ("echo back".equals(event) && args.length > 0) {
                   Log.d("SocketIO", "" + args[0]);
                   // -> "hello"
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onDisconnect() {

           }

           @Override
           public void onConnect() {
               Log.i("CONNECT","just connected");
           }

           @Override
           public void onMessage(String s, IOAcknowledge ioAcknowledge) {
               Log.i("MESSAGE",s);
           }

           @Override
           public void onMessage(JSONObject jsonObject, IOAcknowledge ioAcknowledge) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onError(SocketIOException e) {
               Log.i("ERROR_MESSAGE ",e.getMessage().toString());
           }

       });
       socket.emit("echo", "hello");
```

Logcat:

```
    01-26 17:04:44.996    1904-2291/com.navigation.drawer.activity I/ERROR_MESSAGE﹕ Error while handshaking

    01-26 17:04:44.997    1904-2291/com.navigation.drawer.activity I/io.socket﹕ Cleanup
```

node version    v0.10.31
socket.io version 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access 127.0.0.1(localhost) , from you emulator , because emulators has their own localhost which is I think 12.0.0.2 ( or something ) , so I think if you connect directly to your local ip (E.g : 192.168.1.123 , what ever your local IP is) , it must work